# Compute OS Admin Login role doesn't make user sudoer

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, sudo, google-iam

I have a user with the `Compute OS Admin Login` role, but when I log in using `ssh`, this user is not a `sudoer`. I've tried to restart the instance, but still the same. I've tried with `enable_oslogin:TRUE` both at the instance level and at the project level.

Anything else I should try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` I had `UsePAM` set to `no`.